# How to make UICollectionViewCell live few points outside UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

How to **keep** **Cells** in UICollectionView **live**, still not destroyed on some distance outside from UICollectionView when it's not visible. In Swift :)

I have 2 reasons if it can help:

1. Shadow disappear once Cell is outside View
2. I have animation of custom FlowLayout (zooming out) and it's not perfectly like expected, cell animates from edge, not from few points outside as expected (because animation starts when side Cell was not dequeued yet)

So, as for now, UICollectionViewCell is being destroyed once it's not visible. I need it to be destroyed only when it goes for example by 50 points away from the UICollectionView.
I need only original cells, not any kind of it's snapshots/copies. Thanks.

Comment: You can add top/bottom insets, and move you collection view accordingly

Comment: CZ54, not sure I understand what you mean. How moving collectionview can make the cell living outside it?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @CharithaBasnayake Nope, did not find.